# numbering in ngx-pagination

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using ngx-pagination. I am getting pagination.

[image: This is page 1, I have numbering over here]

Now have a look at the page 2

[image]

in page 2, I am getting index again starting from 1. But I want it from 6 on second page, 11 on 3rd page and so on.

```
<div>
   <li *ngFor="let i = index; let elements of element | paginate: {id: 'elementList', itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p}" class="list-group">
         <a (click)=getElement(i)>{{i+1}}.)&nbsp;{{elements.elemententity}}</a>
   </li>
</div>

<div *ngIf="element.length > 5">
    pagination-controls id="elementList" (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
</div>
```

where element is the array of name and p = 1 both coming from .ts file.

Expected Output:
(on second page)

6.) patient.age

7.) events

8.) products

Comment: i think you are looking for loadmore, pagination usually load current paged data from the server replacing the previous list in the array

Comment: I don't see any problem with your implementation except `let i = index; let elements of element`. Just change its order like this `let elements of element; let i=index`

Comment: @JoelJoseph
The array is continuously changing by adding or removing elements from it.
On Every Add or Remove, this is getting updated, and again rendering new update list.

Comment: @Arcteezy
Thanks, But I tried that also, I am getting the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the `currentPage` to calculate the index.

Something like this:

```
 <a (click)="getElement(i)">{{(p-1) * 5 + i + 1}}.) {{elements.elemententity}}</a>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks...It is working...Only the thing is since p=1, It is starting from 6....So I just subtracted 5 from your expression.